# Regex search string with a not includes

Tags: regex

I have the following content...

```
database-host-12334-ireland
database-host-23233-london
database-host-32323-cardiff
backup-host-2323232-ireland
backup-host-3232323-london
```

I want to be able to search for all database-hosts and at the same time leave out the Ireland host.

I want the search to return only 2 hosts database hosts:

```
database-host-23233-london
database-host-32323-cardiff
```

I cant figure out how I can edit my regex lookup from `^database-host-[0-9].*`

Any help would be appreciated, maybe its not even possible.
Thanks

***UPDATE TO PREVIOUS QUESTION:***

Ok a bit more complicated this time, how would you go about excluding the one database ireland host from this list?

[www.regexr.com/5gln4](http://www.regexr.com/5gln4)

```
database-host-12334.host.zone1.eu.ireland-1
database-host-12334.host.zone1.us.newyork-1
database-host-12334.host.zone2.uk.london-1
database-host-12334.host.zone3.uk.cardiff-1
database-host-12334.host.zone3.uk.belfast-1
backup-host-12334.host.zone2.uk.london-1
backup-host-12334.host.zone3.uk.cardiff-1
backup-host-12334.host.zone3.uk.belfast-1

I only want to return the database-hosts excluding Ireland one.
```

Comment: Use `^(?!.*\bireland\b)database-host-.*`

Comment: Thank you so much, you have saved me and my team so much pain with this one line!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You may use a negative lookahead assertion to rule out the Ireland host:

```
database-host-\d+-(?!ireland)\w+
```

### Demo

If you can't use lookarounds for some reason, another way to logically achieve what you want would be to use *two* regex patterns, one for whitelisting database hosts, and the other for blacklisting Ireland hosts:

```
database-host-\d+-\w+ && !(database-host-\d+-ireland)
```

Comment: This is brilliant thank you, it has me on the right track.
Ok a bit more complicated this time, how would you go about excluding the one database ireland host from this list?

https://regexr.com/5gln4